# RxJS: distinguish single click from drag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rxjs

I have an AngularJS component that should react to either a single click or a drag (resizing an area).

I started to use RxJS (ReactiveX) in my application, so I try to find a solution using it. The Angular side of the request is minor...

To simplify the problem (and to train myself), I made a slider directive, based on the rx.angular.js drag'n'drop example: http://plnkr.co/edit/UqdyB2
See the Slide.js file (the other code is for other experiments). The code of this logic is:

```
    function(scope, element, attributes)
    {
      var thumb = element.children(0);
      var sliderPosition = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
      var sliderWidth = element[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
      var thumbPosition = thumb[0].getBoundingClientRect().left;
      var thumbWidth = thumb[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;

      // Based on drag'n'drop example of rx-angular.js
      // Get the three major events
      var mousedown = rx.Observable.fromEvent(thumb,     'mousedown');
      var mousemove = rx.Observable.fromEvent(element,   'mousemove');
      var mouseup   = rx.Observable.fromEvent($document, 'mouseup');

      // I would like to be able to detect a single click vs. click and drag.
      // I would say if we get mouseup shortly after mousedown, it is a single click;
      // mousedown.delay(200).takeUntil(mouseup)
      //   .subscribe(function() { console.log('Simple click'); }, undefined, function() { console.log('Simple click completed'); });

      var locatedMouseDown = mousedown.map(function (event) 
      {
        event.preventDefault();
        // console.log('Click', event.clientX - sliderPosition);
        // calculate offsets when mouse down
        var initialThumbPosition = thumb[0].getBoundingClientRect().left - sliderPosition;
        return { from: initialThumbPosition, offset: event.clientX - sliderPosition };
      });

      // Combine mouse down with mouse move until mouse up
      var mousedrag = locatedMouseDown.flatMap(function (clickInfo) 
      {
        return mousemove.map(function (event)
        {
          var move = event.clientX - sliderPosition - clickInfo.offset;
          // console.log('Move', clickInfo);
          // calculate offsets from mouse down to mouse moves
          return clickInfo.from + move;
        }).takeUntil(mouseup);
      });

      mousedrag 
        .map(function (position)
        {
          if (position < 0)
            return 0;
          if (position > sliderWidth - thumbWidth)
            return sliderWidth - thumbWidth;
          return position;
        })
        .subscribe(function (position) 
        {
          // console.log('Drag', position);
          // Update position
          thumb.css({ left: position + 'px' });
        });
    }
```

That's mostly D'n'D constrained horizontally and to a given range.

Now, I would like to listen to mousedown, and if mouse up happens within a short while (say 200 ms, to adjust), I see it as a click and I do a specific treatment (eg. resetting the position to zero).

I tried with `delay().takeUntil(mouseup)`, as seen in another SO answer, without success. Perhaps a switch() might be needed, too (to avoid going the drag route).

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `timeout` (`timeoutWith` if you are using ReactiveX/RxJS)

```
var click$ = mousedown.flatMap(function (md) {
  return mouseup.timeoutWith(200, Observable.empty());
});
```

If the mouseup doesn't occur before the timeout it will just propagate an empty `Observable` instead. If it does then the downstream observer will receive an event.

Comment: It works with `timeout()`. I found no `timeoutWith` in the RxJS library, at v.4.0, but there is a `timeoutWithSelector` which is only available in a lite sub-library, apparently. It seems it does the same thing than the second version of `timeout`. Maybe it is just a legacy thing.
Anyway, it works. So thanks.

Comment: @PhiLho `timeoutWith` is part of [RxJS vNext](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS). RxJS 4.0 is still under the Reactive-Extensions project, so it is using `timeout`. You had mentioned ReactiveX which is why I mentioned it. But glad to help!

Comment: vNext? Sigh. Name is as stupid as ESNext... ;-) Each version is the "next one", somehow... I understand it is to mark a major update / change, but still, name is non-sense. I suppose vNext will be v.5 eventually?
Anyway, you pushed me in the right direction (see updates on Plunker if you want), so thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't the trick with `delay(Xms).takeUntil(mouseup)` doing the opposite of what you want? I mean, you want to detect when the `mouseup` event happens before the countdown, while the aformentioned trick detect when the mouseup event happens after.

I would try something around those lines (untested for now, but hopefully it will orient you in some positive direction):

```
var click$ = mousedown.flatMap(function ( mouseDownEv ) {
  return merge(
      Rx.just(mouseDownEv).delay(Xms).map(function ( x ) {return {event : 'noclick'};}),
      mouseup.map(function ( mouseUpEv ) {return {event : mouseUpEv};})
      ).first();
});
```

The idea is to race the `mouseup` event against a dummy emission happening after your delay, and see who wins. So if `click$` emits 'noclick' then you can consider that no click happened.

Hopefully that works, i will test soon but if you do before me, let me know.

Comment: I haven't tried (yet?) because I first tried @paulpdniels' answer, which is simpler... and works. But I appreciate the answer, which shows an interesting technique. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, the answer you chose is the best no doubt, I did not know about that operator, there are so many of them, it is hard to get your head around all of them

Comment: +1, that's why I ask questions, as I have to adapt my mind to the Rx way of thinking... Trying to answer questions is also a good way to explore the API, once you master the bases... :-D