# Smarter buffers

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I send request - get an array of data. In order to manipulate that data I need to flatten it, so I can use it as a stream of entities not stream of array of entities but, then on side-effect I want those entities appear in the UI at once, not one by one, so it updates UI only ones at a time.

Let's say I have a code like this:

```
// this generates a sequence of objects - getCasesStream sends an ajax request,
// whenever dateRange changes 
casesStm = dateRangeStm.flatMapLatest(getCasesStream)

casesStm.subscribe((x)=> { console.log(x) })

function getCasesStream(dateRange) {
    return getCases(dateRange.startDate, dateRange.endDate)  
        // api every time returns an array,
        // but it's difficult to work with array of elements, ergo the flattening
        .flatMap((x) => x)                                
        .filter((x) => _.isNotEmpty(x.value))
        .map((caseDoc) => _.assign(caseDoc.value, {
            key: caseDoc.id
        }));
}
```

This works just fine, emits one value at a time. Now what I want is to emit at most 10 values, if there are less than 10 - emit whatever left.

I thought I could solve that by doing this:

```
casesStm
    .windowWithCount(10)
    .flatMap((x)=> x.toArray())
```

But then this only works if `getCasesStream` (after filtering) returns at least 10 items, if it has less than that - I won't even see them.

How can I buffer elements effectively here? again:

- api sends us an array
- to filter and add additional props to each element it's better to flatten that array (or maybe not?)
- at the end I need to buffer (don't want to force browser to redraw each time new element comes)

Maybe I should use generic `window` that returns length of elements in `getCasesStream` but that function doesn't take any arguments, how can I get the length? I tried using `windowWithTimeOrCount` - that keeps emitting empty buffer every interval, even when there's no elements.

Comment: By emit 10 items do you mean that for any one request to getCases you only want to show at most 10 cases?

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out those empty buffer and alternatively you could review some of the options mentioned in [How to create a RxJS buffer that groups elements in NodeJS but that does not rely on forever running interval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33402737/how-to-create-a-rxjs-buffer-that-groups-elements-in-nodejs-but-that-does-not-rel).

The idea showcased there is to use the operator `buffer` with closing selector. As a closing selector, you could use `merge(source.skip(9).take(1).repeat(), source.delay(Xms))` (or the operator `flatMapFirst` as proposed as well in the link thereaforementioned, review both options). In that way, in principle when there is no case emitted, there is no buffer emitted, and when a case arrive, the `merge` operator emits a value either on the 10th case, or Xms after, whichever is first. When the value from the `merge` operator is emitted, the buffer is closed and emitted.

You can take inspiration from the code here:

```
function emits(who){
  return function (x) { console.log([who, "emits"].join(" ") + " " + x + " click(s)");};
}

var Xms = 1700;

var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.body, 'click');
console.log("running");

var delayedSource$ = Rx.Observable.merge(source.skip(9).take(1).repeat(), source.delay(Xms));

var buffered$ = source
     .buffer(function () { return  delayedSource$;}).map(function(clickBuffer){return clickBuffer.length;});

buffered$.subscribe(emits("buffer"));
```

jsbin : http://jsbin.com/siqopuxoli/edit?html,js,console,output

Important note : you should also share your case source (unless you know it is a hot source already), as it will be subscribed several times: `getCases(dateRange.startDate, dateRange.endDate).share()`